# Get response from alert pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show pop-up if the file is does not exist.Here is the code

```
 protected void showMessageBox(string message)
    {
        string jScript;
        message = message.Replace("'", "\'");
        jScript = String.Format("alert('{0}');", message);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", jScript, true);
    }
```

In the page load, I want to check the response from user. If user click OK, after that the window will close. I also want the page will not load if the pop up error open.
Anyone can help how to check the response from the alert that pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You should try something like this:

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.appendFormat("var userResponse = confirm('{0}');", message)
sb.append("if(userResponse){")
sb.append("// do something at OK user response")
sb.append("}")
sb.append("else{")
sb.append("// do something at cancel response")
sb.append("}")

var jScript = sb.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. then how to read the returned boolean value?